# Edit text File in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, file, edit

I was trying to edit a specific value inside text file through c++. My method is to copy all text values to an array edit what i want then overwrite the old file. Everything goes well until:

```
int nm=0;
while (nm < arraysize) {            
  myfile << array1[nm];
  nm++;
}
```

the file doesn't change or add the new value . this is the full function

```
void receptionist::edit_room(int pre1) {
  fstream myfile ("booked.txt");
  int newroom_num;
  cout << "Please Enter The New Room Number You wish : " << endl;
  cin >> newroom_num;
  const int arraysize=20;
  int array1[arraysize];
  int i=0;
  if(myfile.is_open()) {
    while(i < arraysize && myfile >> array1[i]) {
      myfile >> array1[i];
      i++;
    }
    myfile.clear();
    int x=0;
    while (x < arraysize) {
      if ( pre1 == array1[x]) {
        array1[x] = newroom_num;
        break;
      }
      x++;
    }           
    int nm=0;
    while (nm < arraysize ) {
      if (array1[nm]> -1) { // this is how i fixed the garbage values 
        myfile << array1[nm] << endl;
        nm++;
      }
      else {
        break;
      }
    }           
    myfile.close();         
  }
  else {
    cout << "Couldn't Open " << endl ;
  }
};
```

Comment: Please format the code so that it is easier to read - noone likes to read through unformatted code.

Comment: am sorry but i don't know how ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Point 1:**

```
while(!myfile.eof())
{
  myfile >> array1[i];
  i++;
}
```

Better way is:

```
while( i < arraysize && myfile >> array1[i])
{
  i++;
}
```

**Point 2:**

```
while (x<= arraysize){
```

Change `<=` to `<` because `array1[arraysize]` is out of bounds access.

**Point 3:**

Also IMO you should remove this check while writing to file.

```
while (array1[nm]!= EOF){ // remove it.
```

Instead:

```
while (nm < arraysize) { // not <=
 myfile << array1[nm];
 nm++;
}
```

Comment: am sorry but it's still the same i changed to the same as yours

Comment: @BishoyM try to clear the error flags after reading the file by myfile.clear();

Comment: well it started writing but it gives me garbage instead of the value i choose to enter

Comment: @BishoyM Please show your modified full code. Also, for your x and nm loops, they should loop till i and not arraysize (x < i and nm < i).

Comment: i resolved the garbage values but the problem still it doesn't delete the updated value it just adds it give me a sec to put the code